# Within and between factors in regression models in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

I'm trying to run a rmANOVA and a corresponding regression model. In the experiment participants were completing a questionnaire which was evaluating how much of a trait X they have (score). Then they were performing a task, in which each participant was exposed to three conditions (COND - nSCM, SCM, SC). Their brain responses were measured (ERP).

This is how it looks like:

```
 > head(df)
    code    SEX AGE SCORE COND        ERP
1 AA1407   male  29    14 nSCM -3.0348373
2 AN0312   male  26    13 nSCM -1.8799240
3 BR1410   male  23    30 nSCM  0.4284033
4 EZ2404   male  23    23 nSCM -0.7615117
5 HA1012 female  27    22 nSCM -2.9301698
6 HS3004   male  30    16 nSCM -0.5468492
```

Since I am a bit confused about how to use different types of variables in R, maybe someone could also reassure me about the following:

```
> sapply(df,class)
     code       SEX       AGE     SCORE      COND       ERP 
 "factor"  "factor" "numeric" "numeric"  "factor" "numeric"
```

Based on the experimental design, the ANOVA design has one between-subject IV: SCORE, one within-subject IV: COND and the DV is ERP (right?).

This is the model I used and the summary:

```
> anERP <- aov(ERP ~ COND*SCORE, data = df)
> summary(anERP)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
COND         2   0.21   0.105   0.027 0.9736  
SCORE        1  16.87  16.868   4.297 0.0419 *
COND:SCORE   2   0.58   0.289   0.074 0.9291  
Residuals   69 270.85   3.925                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

So, IF this is right (please let me know if anything doesn't seem right), I should also find an effect for SCORE when I build a regression model, right? Also, I'm not sure how to interpret this effect, since AQ is an interval variable (scores in range 6-35). I would appreciate a little help here.

Now I'm very confused about how this model should look like for regression. I started with simple lm model with SCORE and COND as fixed effects:

```
> lmERP <- lm(ERP ~ SCORE*COND, data = df)
> summary(lmERP)

Call:
lm(formula = ERP ~ SCORE * COND, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.2554 -1.0916  0.1975  1.4582  3.3097 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)    -3.04269    1.06193  -2.865  0.00552 **
SCORE           0.06458    0.05229   1.235  0.22108   
CONDSCM        -0.08141    1.50180  -0.054  0.95693   
CONDnSCM        0.36646    1.50180   0.244  0.80795   
SCORE:CONDSCM   0.01111    0.07396   0.150  0.88104   
SCORE:CONDnSCM -0.01707    0.07396  -0.231  0.81814   
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1.981 on 69 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0612,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.006827 
F-statistic: 0.8997 on 5 and 69 DF,  p-value: 0.4864
```

However, here the main effect of SCORE doesn't reach significance. How is it possible? Shouldn't rmANOVA and regression show roughly similar results (or at least the main effects)?
I guess I'm not applying the right linear model here, since it doesn't seem to recognise there are both within and between subject factors in the design.

I have read hundreds of webpages, tutorials and forums and I'm still completely confused about these models. Thank you in advance for any piece of advice!

Answer (score 1):

Repeated-measures or mixed-model designs can be very confusing to specify using R's base `aov` function. In the code you have written, for example, `aov` will treat all the specified factors as independent (i.e., between-subject). I highly recommend using a library that makes it easier to specify these types of designs.

The **ez** library contains `ezANOVA`, which makes these tests simple to perform, provided that all your cases are complete (all factors are fully crossed, with no missing data). Assuming that your `CODE` column uniquely identifies each subject and you wanted to include all factors from your data set, the test would look something like this:

```
my.aov <- ezANOVA(data = df, dv = ERP, wid = CODE, between = .(SEX, AGE, SCORE), within = COND).
```

It is also possible to implement these designs with the **lme4** package (in fact, `ezANOVA` is a wrapper around lme4's functions). While lme4 allows for more flexible model specifications and can tolerate incomplete data, its syntax is more difficult. [Bodo Winter's tutorial on lme4](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial.pdf) is a good start, if you want to go really deep.

As an aside, there is usually little point in performing both an ANOVA and a linear regression. Unless the two tests are specified in a way that treats the factors differently, the results will be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was very helpful :)

Comment: I did, but I'm not active enough for my votes to be displayed publicly ;)